# Get student with the lowest grade per teacher

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery, aggregate

Here are my tables:

**Teacher:**

[image]

**Student:**

[image]

**Test**

[image]

a teacher has students, a student takes tests.

```
  SELECT
    t.name as teacherName,
    s.name as studentName,
    t.id as teacherID,
    s.id as studentID,
    MIN(tt.grade) as grade
    FROM teacher t
    JOIN student s ON s.`teacher_id` = t.id
    JOIN test tt ON tt.student_id = s.id
    GROUP BY studentID;
```

so here I get teacher -> student -> lowest grade  (6 rows)

[image]

What I want is

teacher -> student with lowest grade -> the grade  (2 rows)

I can get

teacher -> lowest grade per teacher

but then the student name becomes ambiguous since I'm not grouping by that..

Comment: Still struggling? If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I made a sequel dump in xml, raw sql etc.  sqlfiddle just says:  Unknown Error Occurred: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
t.name as teacherName,
s.name as studentName,
t.id as teacherID,
s.id as studentID,
tt.grade
FROM teacher t
JOIN student s ON s.`teacher_id` = t.id
JOIN test tt ON tt.student_id = s.id
JOIN (
    SELECT 
    t.id teacherID, MIN(grade) AS grade
    FROM teacher t
    JOIN student s ON s.`teacher_id` = t.id
    JOIN test tt ON tt.student_id = s.id
    GROUP BY t.id    
) j
ON j.teacherID = t.id AND j.grade = tt.grade;
```

arghh

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is to join to a derived table, aka a subquery with an alias.

```
select yourfields, temp.something, minvalue
from yourtables
join (
select something, min(value) minvalue
from yourtables
group by something
) temp on someTable.something = temp.something
and value = minvalue
```

You can work out the details.

Comment: Yeah..  I've been trying to do that for the last 2 hours.  Those details could really help right now. haha

Comment: Start small.  Do one thing at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a subtable getting the lowest grade by teacher, and then join to that. Like so:

```
select t.name teacher_name, s.name student_name, x.min_grade
from teacher t
join student s on t.id = s.teacher_id
join test ts on s.id = ts.student_id
join (
  select sx.teacher_id, min(tsx.grade) min_grade
  from student sx
  join test tsx on sx.id = tsx.student_id
  group by 1) x on t.id = x.teacher_id and ts.grade = x.min_grade;
```